# Connecting two mininet in two different VM with the same Ryu Controller

Tags: mininet, sdn, openflow, openvswitch, ryu

I am using virtual box on Windows 10 and running two VMs with ubuntu 18 concurrently
Both of them have mininet installed.

In the VMs settings I have set the network as **Host Only adapter** and in **advanced** selected  allow VMs so that both the VMs can communicate.

I have tried **`$ ifconfig -a`** in both VM and one have ip **192.168.56.101** and the other **192.168.56.102** and tried pinging from one VM to another and it works.

I am running mininet in both of them as given below and connected both of them to the same **Ryu controller** I which is running on VM1.

[image: Fig: The switches are connecting to the controller]

`Fig: The switches are connecting to the controller`

I have used the following commands to do this:

1. In **VM1 terminal1**:

   ```
    ~$ ryu-manager --ofp-tcp-listen-port 6653 ryu/ryu/app/simple_switch_13.py
   ```
2. In **VM1 terminal2**:

   ```
    ~$ sudo mn --topo single,2 --controller remote,ip=192.168.56.101:6653
   ```
3. In **VM2 terminall**:

   ```
    ~$ sudo mn --topo single,2 --controller remote,ip=192.168.56.101:6653
   ```

Now my questions are:

1. How to **ping VM1->hosts** from **VM2 mininet** and vice versa?
2. If ping can be done then how to put **VM1->h1 and VM2->h1** in the same **VLAN** and
   **VM1->h2 and VM2->h2** in the same **VLAN** using ovs commands or anything?